# In a semi-simple module, any submodule is a direct factor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, representation-theory, modules

I need help understanding the following :

> In a semi-simple module, any submodule is a direct factor (this is sometimes taken as the definition of semi-simple)

(i) How is this equivalent to the usual definition i.e. that a semi-simple module is a direct sum of simple modules?

(ii) Does all this generalise to an object in a semi-simple category?

Comment: A good reference is http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111102009/module2/lec4.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the equivalence of the two definitions both directions use Zorns lemma. Given a sub module $N$ of a direct sum of simple modules $M=\sum M_{\alpha}$, chose a maximal set 
$\{M_{\beta}\}$ such that $\{M_{\beta}\}\cup \{N\}$ is independent then show 
$$M=N\oplus \sum M_{\beta}$$

In the other direction, we need to have simple submodules of a complemented module, once we have this we can show that it is the sum of simple submodules. So to show that simple submodules exist,

Take $x \in M$ and $Z$ a maximal submodule such that $x \not \in Z$, $Z$ is has a complement, say $N$, then show that $N$ is minimal.

Unfortunately I am not competent to answer the second question.

Comment: What is a reference for this?

Comment: Nathan Jacobson Basic Algebra II